# Simplificação de função booleana

Tags: booleano, álgebra-booleana

Cheguei em um função booleana e gostaria saber se há uma forma mais simples ou se a minha está certa.

A função é:

[image: função para simplificação]

Eu cheguei na seguinte resposta:

[image: resolução]

Eu estou na dúvida se essa á a solução mais simples que eu poderia chegar...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos montar a tabela-verdade de `f`:

```
w x y z f
0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 1
0 0 1 1 1
0 1 0 0 1
0 1 0 1 0
0 1 1 0 1
0 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 1 0
1 1 0 0 0
1 1 0 1 0
1 1 1 0 1
1 1 1 1 0
```

Vamos reordenar a tabela colocando o `x` na primeira coluna (e reordenar as linhas de forma que o conjunto `xwyz` esteja ordenado de 0000 até 1111):

```
x w y z f
0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 1
0 0 1 1 1
0 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 0
0 1 1 0 1
0 1 1 1 0
1 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 1 1
1 1 0 0 0
1 1 0 1 0
1 1 1 0 1
1 1 1 1 0
```

A primeira metade da tabela é igual a segunda. Ou seja, `x` é irrelevante. Eis como fica a tabela remanescente:

```
w y z f
0 0 0 1
0 0 1 0
0 1 0 1
0 1 1 1
1 0 0 0
1 0 1 0
1 1 0 1
1 1 1 0
```

Há várias expressões possíveis que expressam essa tabela-verdade, e todas elas necessariamente dependem de `w`, `y` e `z` (não há mais nenhuma variável irrelevante).

Outras possíveis ordenações da tabela-verdade são essas:

```
y w z f
0 0 0 1
0 0 1 0
0 1 0 0
0 1 1 0
1 0 0 1
1 0 1 1
1 1 0 1
1 1 1 0
```

```
z w y f
0 0 0 1
0 0 1 1
0 1 0 0
0 1 1 1
1 0 0 0
1 0 1 1
1 1 0 0
1 1 1 0
```

Dentre as possíveis formas de se expressar o conteúdo dessas tabelas, temos:

1. `(NOT w AND NOT z) OR (y AND NOT w) OR (y AND z)` - a sua solução.
2. `(NOT w AND NOT z) OR (y AND (NOT z OR NOT w))` - a solução do Lucas Percisi.
3. `(NOT w AND NOT y AND NOT z) OR (NOT w AND y AND NOT z) OR (NOT w AND y AND z) OR (w AND y AND NOT z)` - listagem das linhas com 1 nas tabelas-verdade.
4. `(NOT w AND NOT y AND NOT z) OR (NOT w AND y) OR (w AND y AND NOT z)` -
   simplificação do 3.
5. `(NOT z AND (w <-> y)) OR (NOT w AND y)` - simplificação do 4.
6. `IF w THEN (y AND NOT z) ELSE (y OR NOT z)` - usando `w` como teste no `IF`.
7. `IF y THEN (w NAND z) ELSE (w NOR z)` - usando `y` como teste no `IF`.
8. `IF z THEN (NOT w AND y) ELSE (NOT w OR y)` - usando `z` como teste no `IF`.
9. `(y AND NOT z) OR (w AND (y <-> z))` - separando os casos onde `y` e `z` são diferentes daqueles em que são iguais.
10. `(NOT w AND y) OR (NOT z AND (w <-> y))` - separando os casos onde `w` e `y` são diferentes daqueles em que são iguais.
11. `(NOT w AND NOT z) OR (y AND (w XOR z))` - separando os casos onde `w` e `z` são diferentes daqueles em que são iguais.

Na minha opinião pesssoal, a solução 7 é a mais simples, mas você pode discordar. Não tem como simplificar muito mais do que essas alternativas que estão aí.

Comment: Obrigado Victor! A resposta me parece bem completa e detalhista, vai ser de grande ajuda! Se não for incomodo eu tenho uma outra pergunta referente a este conteúdo, se puder me ajudar também, segue o link : https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/252471/express%C3%A3o-l%C3%B3gica-e-circuito-correspondente

Comment: na segunda tabela me parece que quando você trocou a coluna X pela W, na verdade você apenas trocou a letra, e não a configuração da coluna. E novamente você re-arranja W com Y e logo após Y com Z, mas as configurações da coluna dessas letras não são modificadas, poderia esclarecer porque?

Comment: @Dwcleb Resposta editada.

Answer (score 0):

cheguei em outra resposta:

F(x,y,w,z) = (!w * !z) + (y * (!z + !w));

Comment: Na vdd vc apenas botou o y em evidência na minha expressão final, correto?