# Expressão lógica e circuito correspondente

Tags: lógica, álgebra-booleana

Possuo a função lógica :

[image: função]

Preciso simplifica-lá ao máximo que eu puder. Dito isto, eu criei a sua tabela verdade e construí o mapa de Karnaugh.

Tabela verdade:
[image: Tabela verdade]

Mapa de Karnaugh [Não sei se está corretamente montado]:
[image: Mapa]

Após eu montar os dois esquemas acima, achei a seguinte simplificação da função:

[image: expressão simplificada]

E o seu circuito correspondente [não me preocupei em fazer o circuito mais simples]:

[image: circuito]

Minha resolução está correta e simplificada nos termos que deveriam ser simplificados ou há convergências na mesma?

Answer (score 1):

Sim está certa. Em questões como esta, simplificação, recomendo ir direto para o mapa Karnaugh.
Além disso, só para complementar sua questão/resposta, vou (1) explicitar seu mapa de Karnaugh e (2) vou mostrar uma maneira mais clara de apresentar sua resposta:

=(1)=
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

=(2)=

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]